# Longest common suffix

Tags: string, scala, functional-programming

I  I would like to find the longest common suffix of two strings in Scala.

```
def longestSuffix(s1: String, s2: String) = {
  val it = (s1.reverseIterator zip s2.reverseIterator) takeWhile {case (x, y) => x == y}
  it.map (_._1).toList.reverse.mkString
}
```

This code is clumsy and probably inefficient (e.g. because of reversing). How would find the longest common suffix *functionally*, i.e. without mutable variables ?

Answer (score 1):

One way to improve it would be to connect reverse and map in last operation:

```
str1.reverseIterator.zip(str2.reverseIterator).takeWhile( c => c._1 == c._2)
.toList.reverseMap(c => c._1) mkString ""
```

firstly make a list, and then reverseMap this list

Answer (score 1):

We can iterate over substrings, without reverse:

```
def longestSuffix(s1: String, s2: String) = {
  s1.substring(s1.length to 0 by -1 takeWhile { n => s2.endsWith(s1.substring(n)) } last)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Interesting but a bit complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Let `tails` produce the sub-strings and then return the first that fits.

```
def longestSuffix(s1: String, s2: String) =
  s1.tails.dropWhile(!s2.endsWith(_)).next
```

Some efficiency might be gained by calling `tails` on the shorter of the two inputs.

Comment: Thanks.Looks nice but I am afraid it's `O(N^2)`

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution like this:

```
def commonSuffix(s1: String, s2: String): String = {
  val n = (s1.reverseIterator zip s2.reverseIterator) // mutable !
            .takeWhile {case (a, b) => a == b}
            .size
  s1.substring(s1.length - n) // is it efficient ?
}
```

Note that I am using `substring` for efficiency (not sure if it's correct).

This solution also is not completely "functional" since I am using `reverseIterator` *despite* it's mutable because I did not find another way to iterate over strings in reverse order. How would you suggest fix/improve it ?